# keyPress Event on div or secction

Tags: knockout.js

Attaching keyPress event  :

**My View Model:**

```
Billing.BillingViewModel = function () {
    this.showSearcherCustomerKeyCommand = function (data, event) {
        if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 49) {
            alert("Combination done !");
        }
    };
};
```

**secction tag on HTML:**

```
<section id="BillHeaderSecction" data-bind="event: { keypress: billingClient.showSearcherCustomerKeyCommand }, valueupdate: 'afterkeydown'">
```

But when I make the combination according to my requirement the event is not executed . How can i attach an event in knockout to div, section, etc rather to inputs . Thanks!

Comment: you can't do that as `keypress` is associated with `<input>, <select> and <textarea>.` you can try using `mouseover and mouseout` . try like this if needed http://jsfiddle.net/74dh736s/26/ . cheers

Comment: But I need that when a final user make the combination keys of ctrl+1 ... Whatever, my app do something, like show popup, hide modal, set focus, etc ... Is not possible with knockout ???

Comment: As far i know things we cant attach events based on keys to sections or divs .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key events will work on section or div when it is having focus. Give tabindex="0" to div element and focus that particular div and press any key, then key event will work.
    `enter code here`  http://jsfiddle.net/qmj0k07w/6/